# what are advantage of using ResourceBundle for reading properties file?

Tags: java, selenium, properties

```
public class Query {
    private final String BUNDLE_NAME="Query";
    private final ResourceBundle RB=ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME);

    public Query(){
    }

    public String getValue(String key) throws FileNotFoundException{
        return RB.getString(key);
    }
}

public class Query_properties {

    public static Properties pos=new Properties();

    public static String sqlData(String q) throws IOException {

    try{
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/Query.properties");
        pos.load(fis);
        pos.getProperty(q);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return pos.getProperty(q);
}
```

Here i use two kind of code which read property file but i am not sure which one fine my selenium automation

Comment: [`ResourceBundle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) is for reading "locale-specific objects" (from javadoc). Do not use `ResourceBundle` if you don't want locale-sensitive objects, e.g. objects that differ between US English and Canadian French or other languages.